# Remove Google Maps info bubble

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone know khow to remove the info bubble from a Google map which appears when the iframe integration code is used ?

Comment: Found the answer here : http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/hide-remove-the-info-window-bubble-on-embedded-google-maps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be change the parameter iwloc=A for iwloc= in your html iframe

Comment: FYI `&amp;` is the escape code for `&` and is the  url parameters seperator, not part of the parameter itself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean. But, anyway, this answer actually works. Could you explain it a little bit more, please?

Comment: the answer is fine. You're just a little mixed up on the syntax and terminology I think.  `iwloc=A&amp` is not a "parameter", `iwloc=A` is. `&amp;` (with the semi-colon) is the escape code for an ampersand, and seperates the different parameters in the query string.  This like may provide some more insight: http://perishablepress.com/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/